# Deserialize json string to an object from a Symfony2 service

Tags: php, json, symfony, serialization, entity

I read this guide about entity's :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html
And this guide about serializer:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html

I have a simple symfony service that i activate from a command module .
The service sends an HTTP request to a remote API and receive back a JSON object.
I want to deserialize that JSON object to a Symfony object so it will be easier to work with (don't want to use the decode and work with and Array).
That JSON object doesn't have any thing to do with my database, I just use it to extract some data that i'll later on need to store in the database.
When i call the deserialize i need to supply the class parameter of the entity :

```
$person = $serializer->deserialize($data, 'Acme\Person', 'xml');
```

but i don't have such an entity.

2 questions :
1.Is it right to create an entity that has no database table? just for data validation and serialize?
2.How can i create a Symfony object from a json string in an easier way?

Comment: Is your class `Acme\Person` have getters and setters? You want deserialize json, but in your code is xml. `$person = $serializer->deserialize($data, 'Acme\Person', 'json');`

Comment: I just copied the example from Symfony docs .
In my code it is JSON